# Need help on phpMyAdmin Configuration

Tags: mysql

I use Windows XP on my Server and Client Machines

On the Server, I install Wamp5 1.7.3

This software installs phpMyAdmin 2.11.0

I want to use this phpMyAdmin from my Client Machines.

What should I do?

If you need any more information please inform me.

I need this solution very urgently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Please add a user with the access privilege in phpMyAdmin and you can access your phpmyAdmin from the clients.

Answer (score 0):

- Start all the services
- Put them Online
- Then, from a client just browse to the server machine. On that page
  there is a link to the phpMyAdmin. Use the IP or hostname, if it has one.

Comment: The client Machine shows that

You are not authorized to view this page. HTTP Error 404 (Forbidden)

Comment: Did you switch it to online?

Comment: Also, 404 is that it doesn't exist... 403 is forbidden. Which is it?

Comment: sorry. typo mistake. that was 403. Yes the server is online from the lower bottom of the context menu. the problem exists.